# How to open browser as a foreground activity like some custom dialog?

Tags: android, listview, browser

I am using below code which onClick of ListView opens a link in browser. Is there any way to open the same browser in some catchy small foreground activity like custom dialog or popup ? Has anyone tried that ?

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(listItems.get(pos).getLink()));

    activity.startActivity(i);

}
```

Thanks,
Advance

Editing Code as per Tarun Suggestion :

```
public class ListListener extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

// List item's reference
List<RssItem> listItems;
// Calling activity reference
Activity activity;

public ListListener(List<RssItem> aListItems, Activity anActivity) {
    listItems = aListItems;
    activity  = anActivity;
}

/**
 * Start a browser with url from the rss item.
 */
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
    /*Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(listItems.get(pos).getLink()));
    activity.startActivity(i);*/
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(ListListener.this);

    alert.setTitle("Title here");
    WebView wv = new WebView(this);

    wv.loadUrl(listItems.get(pos).getLink()); 

    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            view.loadUrl(url);

            return true;
        }
    });

    alert.setView(wv);
    alert.setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
        {
        }
    });
    alert.show();

}
```

}

Error :

07-22 13:18:43.465: E/AndroidRuntime(22759): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-22 13:18:43.465: E/AndroidRuntime(22759): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-22 13:18:43.465: E/AndroidRuntime(22759):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:139)
07-22 13:18:43.465: E/AndroidRuntime(22759):    at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:65)
07-22 13:18:43.465: E/AndroidRuntime(22759):    at android.app.AlertDialog.resolveDialogTheme(AlertDialog.java:142)
07-22 13:18:43.465: E/AndroidRuntime(22759):    at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.(AlertDialog.java:359)
07-22 13:18:43.465: E/AndroidRuntime(22759):    at com.itcuties.multicategoryrssreader.listeners.ListListener.onItemClick(ListListener.java:43)
07-22 13:18:43.465: E/AndroidRuntime(22759):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
07-22 13:18:43.465: E/AndroidRuntime(22759):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1283)
07-22 13:18:43.465: E/AndroidRuntime(22759):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3074)
07-22 13:18:43.465: E/AndroidRuntime(22759):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:4147)
07-22 13:18:43.465: E/AndroidRuntime(22759):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
07-22 13:18:43.465: E/AndroidRuntime(22759):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-22 13:18:43.465: E/AndroidRuntime(22759):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-22 13:18:43.465: E/AndroidRuntime(22759):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
07-22 13:18:43.465: E/AndroidRuntime(22759):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-22 13:18:43.465: E/AndroidRuntime(22759):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-22 13:18:43.465: E/AndroidRuntime(22759):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
07-22 13:18:43.465: E/AndroidRuntime(22759):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
07-22 13:18:43.465: E/AndroidRuntime(22759):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Use webview http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: You want to open a webview in custom dialog m i right ??

Answer (score 1):

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alert.setTitle("Title here");
    WebView wv = new WebView(this);

    wv.loadUrl("http:\\www.google.com");

    wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            view.loadUrl(url);

            return true;
        }
    });

    alert.setView(wv);
    alert.setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id)
        {
        }
    });
    alert.show();
```

Comment: Tarun, but how do i integrate your suggestion with my code...Thanks in advance.

Comment: Inside your on itemclick, copy paste whole code and, In loadUrl do wv.loadUrl(listItems.get(pos).getLink());

Comment: tell me, are you able to do?, Otherwise I will update my ans according to you.

Comment: Tarun, I tried, but it crashed giving Null Pointer Exception. I have added edited my question and added code there. Can you check it. Thanks in advance

Comment: insted of AlertDialog.Builder(this);, do AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivityName.this);

Comment: Nop again the same error....I have again edited my whole code and included including Class

Comment: In webView also you have to do same, WebView wv = new WebView(ListListener.this)

Comment: Nop still the same thing. I hope you are aware of me using activity and not doing this all onCreate ? Is that fine ? I just extended this to Activity to use AlertDialog. Also have mentioned the activity in manifest. It's just that i am concerned with onCreate...Let me try that as well..Meanwhile you can send your opinion too

Comment: I just ran this code, this is perfectly working, just check listItems.get(pos).getLink() is returning appropriate value?

Comment: Strange !! Yes it returns correct link as if i use intent it will work properly

Comment: Why you are not writing onCreate(); ?